# Updating a ViewPager without interrupting the child displayed

Tags: android

I'm building an Android magazine-reader for our campus publication that pulls articles from a web service and displays them in a ViewPager.

To minimize the initial loading time, I want it to pull a relatively small number of articles (say 10) to begin with. Once it has pulled and displayed those articles, I want it to immediately begin downloading/deserializing the next 10 articles while the user is looking through the first set. Likewise, when they reach the 11th article I want it to go ahead and download the next 10, so that the user can continually browse without ever having to wait for more articles to load. This seems easy enough to accomplish using `AsyncTask`s, but I've hit one small hitch: When the next set of articles is downloaded and added to the `ViewPager`, it jumps back to displaying the first page.

How can I add views to the end of the `ViewPager`'s dataset without changing the article being displayed to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will want to use the [Endless Adapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) created commonsware.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can open the page again after refreshing the content of the `ViewPager`. Get the article id of the article user is reading. Open the same article after the `ViewPager` is refreshed.